# Remove '\0' from java string

Tags: java, null, backslash

I want to remove`"\0"` from my java `String`
***Input:***   `"/Test/Test20\06"`
***Result:***   `"/Test/Test206"`
How to do that?

Comment: Where does the 5 at the end come from? Anyway, look for the `replace` method of `String`

Comment: Also, hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, i made mistake  i would like to replace \ from string "/Test/Test20\06" and the result need to be "/Test/Test206" .The replace method don't give the right result...

Comment: My input is not "/Test/Test20\\06". My input comes from external system and it is "/Test/Test20\06"

Comment: To clarify: you have a string with the characters backslash, zero and six or a string literal "... \06" where the last part would be an octal escape.

Answer (score 3):

What you have here is a `String` with an octal value.

```
System.out.println(
    Arrays.toString(
        "/Test/Test20\06".toCharArray()
    )
);
```

> [/, T, e, s, t, /, T, e, s, t, 2, 0, ]

The last character doesn't print because the numeric value is `6` (\06` in octal) and is not a visible character. This is the ACK character.

So you will not be able to replace `\0` using a regex or a `String` replacement method since this is not a `String` but part of the character representation

We can confirm this by replacing some character with a regex (not the solution you want, just for the demo)

```
String s = "/Test/Test20\06";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[\\000-\\011]", "?"));
```

> /Test/Test20?

So you could go with a `Pattern` to capture those value and convert them based on your need. Here is an unsafe solution (the regex only match your case where the octal is at the end.

```
String s = "/Test/Test20\06";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)([\\000-\\011])");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while(m.find()){
    sb.append(m.group(1)).append("" + (int)(m.group(2).charAt(0)));
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sb.toString().toCharArray()));
```

> [/, T, e, s, t, /, T, e, s, t, 2, 0, 6]

Or in a text :

> /Test/Test206

Answer (score 0):

To get the new string with "\" replaced:

```
newStringName = oldStringName.replace("\\", "");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In C there is way to track the end of the string for which which we use '\0' character to denote the end of string.

But when it comes to Java, String is class defined in java.lang package. All the String are instantiated using it. String class tracks the length of strings which have been created and stores the length in the 'length' property of the String. Therefore unlike C, in Java Strings don't terminate with the '\0' character.

Answer (score 0):

As your input `"/Test/Test20\06"`, `"\"` act as a escape sequence. but in this case its act as a ASCII value. to overcome you problem cast you string to char array. then extract last value of it and cast it into int.

solution:

```
String s = "/Test/Test20\06";
char[] c= s.toCharArray();
String ss="";
for(int i= 0; i<c.length-1;i++){
  ss+=c[i];
}
ss+=(int)c[c.length-1];
System.out.println(ss);
```

Comment: That is easy when you know where to look for the octal value ;)

Comment: Yes. i am agree with you. my answer only match for exact given input only. sorry. @AxelH

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out, removing `\0` from your string would damage its content.

As a side note, if one needs to remove `\0` string termination characters surrounding a string, `string.trim()` should work - but not `string.strip()`.